how to add images in the markdown html gradio
i am adding images in my Gradio header, I explored the documentation and found that, it is allowed to keep markdown or html and load images and apply CSS on it to make it stylized, however I have tried and it doesn't load the images properly.
import gradio as gr
gr.HTML("<img  src='image.png' alt='image One'>")


i have explored and found that we need to modify the code to add images in html
import gradio as gr

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    # add file before your image file path
    gr.HTML("<img src='file/image.png' alt='image One'>")

# add allowed_path  in launch
demo.launch(allowed_paths=["."])

